# CheckBox checked on scroll automatically in ListView in android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-arrayadapter

I am newbie to android and have implemented a listView with checkbox and textViews, I am facing a weird issue of selection.

When I am checking any checkbox, all the other checkbox are automatically checked and it is changed after scrolling randomly.

Can anybody help me what changes should I make to fix this in my code?

**ServiceAdapter**

```
package one.tusk.stush.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.company.stush.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import one.tusk.stush.other.Const;

public class ServiceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contArray;
    SparseBooleanArray mArray;


    private Context mContext;
    String resnID, reson;
    Intent i;

    public ServiceAdapter(Context paramContext, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contList) {
        this.mContext = paramContext;
        this.contArray = contList;
        mArray = new SparseBooleanArray(contList.size());

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.contArray.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
        return Integer.valueOf(paramInt);
    }

    public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
        return paramInt;
    }

    public View getView(final int paramInt, View paramView,
            ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater localLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                .getSystemService("layout_inflater");
        Viewholder localViewholder = null;
        Const.selectedIDs.clear();
        if (paramView == null) {
            paramView = localLayoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.raw_single_contact, paramViewGroup, false);
            localViewholder = new Viewholder();

            localViewholder.tv_name = ((TextView) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_name));
            localViewholder.chk_id = ((CheckBox) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.chk_id));

            paramView.setTag(localViewholder);


        } else {

            localViewholder = (Viewholder) paramView.getTag();
            localViewholder.chk_id.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            localViewholder.chk_id.setChecked(mArray.get(paramInt));
        }
        localViewholder.tv_name.setText(contArray.get(paramInt).get("serviceText"));
        localViewholder.chk_id.setChecked(mArray.get(paramInt));
        //localViewholder.chk_id.setChecked(false);
        //localViewholder.chk_id .setTag(paramInt);

        localViewholder.chk_id.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                try {


                    if (isChecked) {
                        Const.selectedIDs.add(contArray.get(paramInt));
                        Const.serviceArrayList.get(paramInt).put("flag", "1");
                    } else {
                        Const.selectedIDs.remove(contArray.get(paramInt));
                        Const.serviceArrayList.get(paramInt).put("flag", "0");
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });




        return paramView;

    }

    static class Viewholder {


    TextView tv_name;
    CheckBox chk_id;


    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SparseBooleanArray` instead of `ArrayList<Boolean>`

```
SparseBooleanArray mArray;
public ServiceAdapter(Context paramContext, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contList) {
    this.mContext = paramContext;
    this.contArray = contList;
    mArray = new SparseBooleanArray(data.size());

}
```

And inside `getView()`

```
if (convertView == null) {

    localViewholder = new Holder();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);

    ....
    ....

    convertView.setTag(localViewholder );

} else {
    localViewholder = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
    localViewholder.chk_id.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    localViewholder.chk_id.setChecked(mArray.get(position));
}
localViewholder.chk_id.setChecked(mArray.get(position));
localViewholder.chk_id.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new
             OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        mArray.put(paramInt, isChecked);
        if (isChecked) {
            Const.selectedIDs.add(isChecked);
            Const.serviceArrayList.get(paramInt).put("flag", "1");
        } else {
            Const.selectedIDs.remove(contArray.get(isChecked));
            Const.serviceArrayList.get(paramInt).put("flag", "0");
        }
    }
});
```

Happy Coding..

Comment: I have edited my code as per your suggestion,Still no change..!!!Please check my edited code

Comment: please check `onChackChangeListener` in my code. and put `mArray.put(paramInt, isChecked);` inside it.

Comment: What is "cb" in your code? and what is "chk_id" both are checkboxes?

Comment: I'm sorry.. cb is chk_id. I actually converted my code to yours. but i think i forgot to change there.. check my updated answer..

Comment: always happy to help ..  :)

Comment: -can you help me for one more problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37804336/soft-keyboard-not-open-in-android?noredirect=1#comment63073463_37804336 .please check it

Answer (score 0):

***Change your adapter class code with this***

```
 public class ServiceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contArray;
        ArrayList<Boolean> checked;


        private Context mContext;
        String resnID, reson;
        Intent i;

        public ServiceAdapter(Context paramContext, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contList) {
            this.mContext = paramContext;
            this.contArray = contList;
            checked = new ArrayList<>();

        }

        public int getCount() {
            return this.contArray.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
            return Integer.valueOf(paramInt);
        }

        public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
            return paramInt;
        }

        public View getView(final int paramInt, View paramView,
                ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
            LayoutInflater localLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                    .getSystemService("layout_inflater");
            Viewholder localViewholder = null;
            Const.selectedIDs.clear();

                paramView = localLayoutInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.raw_single_contact, paramViewGroup, false);
                localViewholder = new Viewholder();

                localViewholder.tv_name = ((TextView) paramView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_name));
                localViewholder.chk_id = ((CheckBox) paramView
                        .findViewById(R.id.chk_id));

                paramView.setTag(localViewholder);


            localViewholder.tv_name.setText(contArray.get(paramInt).get("serviceText"));
            localViewholder.chk_id.setChecked(false);
            localViewholder.chk_id .setTag(paramInt);

            localViewholder.chk_id.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    try {


                        if (isChecked) {
                            Const.selectedIDs.add(contArray.get(paramInt));
                            Const.serviceArrayList.get(paramInt).put("flag", "1");
                        } else {
                            Const.selectedIDs.remove(contArray.get(paramInt));
                            Const.serviceArrayList.get(paramInt).put("flag", "0");
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });




            return paramView;

        }

        static class Viewholder {


        TextView tv_name;
        CheckBox chk_id;


        }



    }
```

Comment: Hello Abhishek,I have used your adapter,But when i am scrolling the listView ti removes the selection..:(

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this

```
localViewholder.chk_id.setChecked(false);
```

to this

```
localViewholder.chk_id.setChecked(localViewholder.chk_id.isChecked());
```